# Issue re-rendering a <ui:include /> in Richfaces 4.0

Tags: datatable, jsf-2, richfaces

I am using richfaces 4.0 final. I have a page where I am including another facelet using

```
<ui:include src="#{bean.selectedPage}" />
```

The String selectedPage is set on a button click. When button is clicked, the page is changed and panel surrounding the above code is re-rendered using "render" attribute. The facelet has a datatable. eg:

```
<rich:dataTable>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <rich:columnGroup>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="hello" />
            </rich:column>
        </rich:columnGroup>
    </f:facet>
</rich:dataTable>
```

The css for this datatable is not included. Could someone help me resolve this issue ? I have added all required jars. This following is a snippet of my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinningClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The strange part is the skin is loaded for other components like <a4j:commandButton /> . Issues appear only for datatable.

Comment: Does this occur on all popular webbrowsers? (Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari, etc?)

Comment: Yes. I dug deeper and I found this. If I change the page on click of a button i.e. if I change selectedPage in <ui:include src="#{bean.selectedPage}" /> then it gives issues. If I initialize my selectedPage to required page or hard code the page like <ui:include src="/page.xhtml" />  it works. However, if I change the page, it wont work. How to get arround this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this before. AFAIK, richfaces loads the CSS for components on demand. Since your page is loaded dynamically, Richfaces never loads the css cause it never knows. (mentioning hard coded page name,framework already knows what component's css to render,and so it does, as you mentioned in your comment).
The only solution I could find for this was to include a `rich:dataTable` in your parent page (i.e. the page in which you are including this facelet with `<ui:include>`) and set its style to `display:none`. This way the framework includes the `rich:dataTable` css before-hand.
I know its not a perfect solution, but I couldn't find a better one!

Comment: I have done something like this. I put the <ui:include src="/page.xhtml"/> inside <a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{bean.selectedPage == '/page.xhtml'}" />. Its a workaround but it works.